# Play server randomly unable to establish connection to Mysql

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.4, hikaricp

So for the last few days I have been plagued by this issue and I am not sure what is causing it or where to start looking.  I am running Play 2.4.1, Anorm 2.5, MySql 5.6 on Amazon Beanstalk using a docker container (T2.Small) + RDS(T2.micro).  I get intermittent issues when making API requests to the server.  My log file is full the error below.  It is complaining that the connection to the DB timed out but if I check RDS it still shows all the connections active.  If I remote into the MySql server and run `SHOW processlist` I see all the connections and they all say Command: Sleep.  Sometimes if I just let the server sit for a few minutes it starts working again.  If I restart the Play app it starts working again immediately.  I can't seem to reliably recreate any set of events that causes it.

Any suggestions or hints on where to start looking would be greatly appreciated because this is driving me nuts.

```
 [ERROR] from play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-186 - Cannot invoke the action
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 30000ms of waiting for a connection.]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 30000ms of waiting for a connection.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227) ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182) ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93) ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:153) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:149) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.db.DB$.withConnection(DB.scala:61) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at utils.Util$.getCurrentPersonIdAndRole(Util.scala:29) ~[datagem.datagem-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
at utils.globals$UserAction$.invokeBlock(globals.scala:128) ~[datagem.datagem-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
at utils.globals$UserAction$.invokeBlock(globals.scala:122) ~[datagem.datagem-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:493) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:741) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:741) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.  In one spot in code I was using DB.getConnection instead of DB.withConnection{} and I was forgetting to release the connection back into the pool.  So after calling the offending function 10 times the pool of connection was empty but still active so all other calls failed.